# Low power Wi-Fi embedded modules recommendation?

Tags: embedded, wifi, low-power

I am evaluating my options for low power embedded wifi modules for an upcoming project, and I was wondering whether the hivemind has had any experience with any of the commercially available ones? The main requirements for me are that it be as low power as possible, and that it has a serial interface (UART/SPI/I2C). I am not considering standalone radio modules.

I am considering:

- Gainspan GS1500M
- Microchip MRF24WB0Mx
- Redpine Signals RS9110-N-11-02
- Taiyo Yuden WYSBMVGX4
- connectBlue OWL211a

If you have used any of these modules, I would welcome your impressions of them. Also, I would greatly appreciate suggestions for other chipsets or any other related advice.

Thank you!

Comment: what is your budget?

Answer (score 2):

[Digi](http://www.digi.com/) has been a manufacturer of Xbee ZigBee modules for some time now, and has recently released [similar modules for Wifi](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/zigbee-rf-modules/point-multipoint-rfmodules/xbee-wi-fi#overview).

[image]

They simply connect to the microcontroller using DIN, DOUT, CTS and RTS, as shown in the picture.

[image]

Not sure if this qualifies as low power, but spec says 140mA receive current and up to 260mA transmit current.

Comment: Those power requirements are in the ballpark, although I wish they could be lower. Have you had experience in using this module with WPA or WPA2 authentication? Thanks!

Comment: @mateja - No experience with those, sorry. I received a mailing from my distri about their release just last week, so I guess they're brand new.

Answer (score 2):

try Roving Networks: http://www.rovingnetworks.com/wi-fi-modules.php
works very good for me. Has all your interfaces, 4uA in stand by and very fast (12ms or so) access to get onto the network. + all required sw. Easy to use.

Good luck.

Hans

Answer (score 1):

We have used the Microchip 802.15 module, and it seemed to work.

Comment: Did you develop an application that ran on the module or did you used it as a standalone module? Have you tried using it with WPA or WPA2 authentication? Does it have an AT command set? Thanks!

Comment: We used their MiWi stack with the 802.15 module and developed our own application above that.  WPA and WPA2 are issues for WiFi, not 802.15.  We have also used the Microchip WiFi module in native mode to add a driver for it in our own network stack for the PIC 18.